# How can I use git4idea to run git blame as a range. Like if I was doing something like git blame -L README.md 1,5 manually?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I use git4idea to run git blame as a range? Like if I was doing something like `git blame -L README.md 1,5` manually? I've tried:

First I start by definining history as `val history = git4idea.history.GitFileHistory;` and then I've tried:

- `blameResult = history.collectHistory(project, filePath, startLine, endLine)` as a variation of the original approach without the line range, so just the project and filePath parameters (compliation fails)
- Using exec (compiles and run but blame doens't actually run)
- Getting the whole history for the file and slicing the array of commit hashes using `startLine` and `endLine` as the slicing indexes (it's not the same thing)